# How to display text of both Chinese and Japanese?

Tags: php

I am using the php plugin "h5ai" to share all file in the directory.
Meanwhile, my files include Chinese and Japanese titles.
I have used the method from: [1](http://bsb.dip.jp/blog/2017/01/15/windows-h5ai/)
to resolve the encoding problem.

```
 public function to_href($path, $trailing_slash = true) {
    $path = mb_convert_encoding( $path, "UTF-8" , "SJIS" );
```

Encoding for Chinese: Big5;and Japanese: SJIS

The major problem is that, this way only resolve the encoding problem of either one language, for instance, if I change encoding for Chinese, Japanese file won't be able to display.

Is it a possible way to display both files of Chinese and Japanese title?

Answer (score 1):

You can define multiple from_encoding type separated by comma or an array of from_encoding. For example:

```
public function to_href($path, $trailing_slash = true) {
    $path = mb_convert_encoding( $path, "UTF-8" , "Big5, SJIS" );
}
```

Please find `mb_convert_encoding` function details here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

Comment: It is not working, perhaps some folders include both languages

Comment: I see, please let us know your solution